# SATA controller

Tags: controller, sata

While start' up the controller *MARVEL* (IDE mode) set the status register is set to "BUSY".

What is the reason for "BUSY" status? And what action shall be performed in order to fix this status?

Comment: well, i don't know MARVEL, but usually that means it's doing something. without more detail it just seems to be working as intended for me... with detail i mean like, does it stay busy, for hours but shouldn't?

Comment: @avi Please put in more time to describe your problem in more detail, it is also a good idea to include the links of other SO questions you have researched and screen captures that show any code or error messages you might have.